# Does the ability to manipulate your environment affect the type of intelligence?

Tags: social-psychology, intelligence, animal-cognition, behaviorism

There are several animals on earth that show certain kinds of intelligence. Some animals have extensions to manipulate their environment and some do not. Think of humans and squids (hand/extension side) versus whales and dolphins on the other (the no hand side).
Learning how to use their hands also gives babies a boost in their development.

My question is: **Does the ability to manipulate your environment affect the type of intelligence?**

I'm pretty sure that it affects the, let's call it generalized intelligence, but does it also change the type from more or less aggressive?

Comment: What do you mean, 'Type' of intelligence? Are you arguing there is a correlation between the amount of limbs one has and how 'aggressive' a being is?

Comment: Perhaps the following would be a useful starting point for theoretically grounding your question:  Wasserman, E. A. (1993)  Comparative Cognition: Beginning the Second Century of the Study of Animal Intelligence. Psychological Bulletin, 113 - 211-228 [PDF](http://www.niu.edu/user/tj0dgw1/pdf/learning/wasserman1993.pdf).

Comment: @StevenJeuris yes, exaclty!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you out, but you could bump this question by editing it, taking [Jeromy's comment](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/849/does-the-ability-to-manipulate-your-environment-affect-the-type-of-intelligence#comment1734_849) into account. Perhaps you find the answer yourself. :) Don't forget you can also answer your own question.

Comment: This question is very vague. What are the different 'types' of intelligence? How is aggressiveness related to anything? Also, please try to cite some of your claims like " Learning how to use their hands also gives babies a boost in their development." A boost in the development of what? Hand use (tautology)? Or general qualities associated with intelligence but not directly related to having hands: say language use?

Comment: I think you might be on to something, drak.  Beings with more "power" to manipulate their environment, could perhaps have a greater logical, cause-effect intelligence, since they have more experience in producing causes and observing effects.  A squid with limited ability to "cause" things will not have such a great understanding of cause-effect relationships.

Comment: Where would you put birds?  They don't have any more grabby appendages than dolphins, but there is quite a lot of work on various species' tool creation and use showing that they do modify their environment.

Comment: @Krysta interesting, have you seen Alfred Hitchcock's "The birds"? Honestly, I have no idea, but if someone would force me to answer, I would put them on the more aggressive side. What do you think? Some time ago I thought about posting a question like:"Dinosaur and Birds have common ancestors. Could they have a common level of intelligence?", but I'm still not sure if this question would fit here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question until "aggressiveness" and the desired demonstrations of intelligence are clarified.